# findInterval() with right-closed intervals

Tags: r, binary-search

The great `findInterval()` function in R uses left-closed sub-intervals in its `vec` argument, as shown in its docs:

> if `i <- findInterval(x,v)`, we have `v[i[j]] <= x[j] < v[i[j] + 1]`

If I want right-closed sub-intervals, what are my options?  The best I've come up with is this:

```
findInterval.rightClosed <- function(x, vec, ...) {
  fi <- findInterval(x, vec, ...)
  fi - (x==vec[fi])
}
```

Another one also works:

```
findInterval.rightClosed2 <- function(x, vec, ...) {
  length(vec) - findInterval(-x, -rev(vec), ...)
}
```

Here's a little test:

```
x <- c(3, 6, 7, 7, 29, 37, 52)
vec <- c(2, 5, 6, 35)
findInterval(x, vec)
# [1] 1 3 3 3 3 4 4
findInterval.rightClosed(x, vec)
# [1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 4
findInterval.rightClosed2(x, vec)
# [1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

But I'd like to see any other solutions if there's a better one.  By "better", I mean "somehow more satisfying" or "doesn't feel like a kludge" or maybe even "more efficient". =)

(Note that there's a `rightmost.closed` argument to `findInterval()`, but it's different - it only refers to the final sub-interval and has a different meaning.)

Comment: What do you think about: `findInterval(x, c(-Inf, head(vec, -1)))`?

Comment: @sgibb that doesn't seem to do the trick, I added an example and yours doesn't give the same result.

Comment: I'm a bit befuddled here, but does `findInterval(x-1,vec)` do what you are looking for?

Comment: @thelatemail, as long as it's just integers?

Comment: I think it is ok to post answers to your own question. My vote would go to your `findInterval.rightClosed2`.

Comment: Another desirable property would be that it works with types other than numeric (e.g. `POSIXt` objects, but ideally anything with comparison operators), as `findInterval` does (`findInterval` works with anything that supports an `as.double` method). The first function above succeeds, but the second fails, because there's no way to negate `POSIXt` objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:** Major clean-up in all aisles.

You might look at `cut`. By default, `cut` makes left open and right closed intervals, and that can be changed using the appropriate argument (`right`). To use your example:

```
x <- c(3, 6, 7, 7, 29, 37, 52)
vec <- c(2, 5, 6, 35)
cutVec <- c(vec, max(x)) # for cut, range of vec should cover all of x
```

Now create four functions that should do the same thing: Two from the OP, one from Josh O'Brien, and then `cut`. Two arguments to `cut` have been changed from default settings: `include.lowest = TRUE` will create an interval closed on both sides for the smallest (leftmost) interval. `labels = FALSE` will cause `cut` to return simply the integer values for the bins instead of creating a factor, which it otherwise does.

```
findInterval.rightClosed <- function(x, vec, ...) {
  fi <- findInterval(x, vec, ...)
  fi - (x==vec[fi])
}
findInterval.rightClosed2 <- function(x, vec, ...) {
  length(vec) - findInterval(-x, -rev(vec), ...)
}
cutFun <- function(x, vec){
    cut(x, vec, include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE)
}
# The body of fiFun is a contribution by Josh O'Brien that got fed to the ether.
fiFun <- function(x, vec){
    xxFI <- findInterval(x, vec * (1 + .Machine$double.eps))
}
```

Do all functions return the same result? Yup. (notice the use of `cutVec` for `cutFun`)

```
mapply(identical, list(findInterval.rightClosed(x, vec)),
  list(findInterval.rightClosed2(x, vec), cutFun(x, cutVec), fiFun(x, vec)))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Now a more demanding vector to bin:

```
x <- rpois(2e6, 10)
vec <- c(-Inf, quantile(x, seq(.2, 1, .2)))
```

Test whether identical (note use of `unname`)

```
mapply(identical, list(unname(findInterval.rightClosed(x, vec))),
  list(findInterval.rightClosed2(x, vec), cutFun(x, vec), fiFun(x, vec)))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

And benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(findInterval.rightClosed(x, vec), findInterval.rightClosed2(x, vec),
  cutFun(x, vec), fiFun(x, vec), times = 50)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
# 1                    cutFun(x, vec)  35.46261  35.63435  35.81233  36.68036  53.52078
# 2                     fiFun(x, vec)  51.30158  51.69391  52.24277  53.69253  67.09433
# 3  findInterval.rightClosed(x, vec) 124.57110 133.99315 142.06567 155.68592 176.43291
# 4 findInterval.rightClosed2(x, vec)  79.81685  82.01025  86.20182  95.65368 108.51624
```

From this run, `cut` seems to be the fastest.

Comment: Thanks.  I seem to recall that `cut` is less efficient, and it also doesn't allow trailing off the right edge of `vec` like `findInterval` does (see rows 15-17 in your output), but that part could be worked around by adding an `Inf` at the end.

Comment: @KenWilliams, yeah, covering the whole range of `x` with `breaks` allows you to cut up all of `x` (see my edit, too). As to the efficiency, well, the code already exists at least.

Comment: @KenWilliams, if you count speed in efficiency benchmarking, there might not be all that much of a difference between `findInterval` and `cut` after all. Perhaps the slowdown in `cut` usually comes from conversion to a factor and label-making?

Comment: For completeness, could you include the OP's solutions as well in your timings...?

Comment: @KenWilliams, if you wish, please see the major update above with (speed) benchmarking.

Comment: Surprising results!  I get similar numbers on my machine.  It looks like I should switch my code to `cutFun`.  And maybe the docs for `cut` need to be updated to remove the disclaimer about speed.

Comment: @KenWilliams, I was surprised, too. And I just found `news(grepl("^PERF", Category) & grepl("cut",Text))`, so the docs very well might be out of date.

Comment: One subtle difference to note: `findInterval` only requires that the cutpoints are non-decreasing, but `cut` requires that they're strictly increasing.  Working around that would probably make `cutFun` lose the speed battle.

Comment: @eddi, could you provide an example of `fiFun` failing? The couple of examples I ran seemed to return expected results.

Comment: I still prefer OP's solutions because of e.g. this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184947/cut-error-breaks-are-not-unique

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the option left.open:

```
findInterval(x, vec, left.open=T)
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

Comment: Yes - this option was added in R version 3.3.2, released in October 2016.  It's now the right way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

If your limits are intervals you simply can grow the right interval a bit: interval+c(0,0.1) would do: findinterval(value, interval+c(0,0.1))

Comment: This won't work for a variety of reasons.  Most fundamentally, recycling will cause this to change the right interval on every odd entry, not all of them.  Further, this assumes that you know that the discretization of the data is wider than 0.1.