# Get lower and upper bounds from `cut` as numeric values

Tags: r, cut

I've read this question here:
[Convert continuous numeric values to discrete categories defined by intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559076/group-numeric-values-by-the-intervals)

However, I would like to output a numeric (rather than a factor), specifically the numeric value of the lower and/or upper bounds (in separate columns)

In essence, this is right, except that the 'df$start' and 'df$end' are given as factors:

```
df$start <- cut(df$x, 
                breaks = c(0,25,75,125,175,225,299),
                labels = c(0,25,75,125,175,225),
                right = TRUE)

df$end <- cut(df$x, 
              breaks = c(0,25,75,125,175,225,299),
              labels = c(25,75,125,175,225,299),
              right = TRUE)
```

The use of `as.numeric()` returns the level of the factor (i.e. values 1-6) rather than the original numbers.

Comment: You could cast using `as.character` first, and then `as.numeric`.  I feel like there should be a better solution to this problem, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing at what you want, since if you wanted the "original numbers", you could just use `df$x`. I presume you are after some number to reflect the group? In that guess, what about the following.

```
## Generate some example data
x = runif(5, 0, 300)
## Specify the labels
labels = c(0,25,75,125,175,225)
## Use cut as before
y = cut(x, 
    breaks = c(0,25,75,125,175,225,300),
    labels = labels,
    right = TRUE)
```

When we convert `y` to a numeric, this gives the index of the label. Hence,

```
labels[as.numeric(y)]
```

or simpler

```
labels[y]
```

Comment: In fact, probably better to save the breaks, and not use the labels at all -- if factor levels is all we need, it doesn't matter whether we use the autogenerated labels.  So just `df$start <- breaks[cut(df$x, breaks=breaks, right=TRUE)]`

Comment: Thanks both. Both the answer and the comment solve the problem @user295691

Answer (score 14):

Much of the behavior of `cut` is related to creating the labels that you're not interested in.  You're probably better off using `findInterval` or `.bincode`.

You would start with the data

```
set.seed(17)
df <- data.frame(x=300 * runif(100))
```

Then set the breaks and find the intervals:

```
breaks <- c(0,25,75,125,175,225,299)
df$interval <- findInterval(df$x, breaks)
df$start <- breaks[df$interval]
df$end <- breaks[df$interval + 1]
```

Comment: +1 for `.bincode`.  I had only seen `findInterval` before.  Now trying to figure out what the key differences are between them.  It looks like there is a difference in handling values at the breaks, they are moved up to the next level in `findInterval` but not `.bincode`.  And points outside the breaks map to NA in `.bincode`, and 0 or N in `findInterval` under default arguments

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 this question had made me curious enough to go down to the source level; it really seems like these functions are practically identical in their algorithm and an interesting project would be to consolidate the implementation into a single function with options to support the required behaviors from both, probably by transforming the output of a single function.

Answer (score 5):

I would go for the usage of regex since all the information is in the output of `cut`.

```
cut_borders <- function(x){
pattern <- "(\\(|\\[)(-*[0-9]+\\.*[0-9]*),(-*[0-9]+\\.*[0-9]*)(\\)|\\])"

start <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern,"\\2", x))
end <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern,"\\3", x))

data.frame(start, end)
}
```

The pattern in words:

- Group 1: either a `(` or a `[`, so we use `(\\(|\\[)`.
- Group 2: number might be negative, so we (`-*`), we are looking for at least one number (`[0-9]+`) which can have decimal places, i.e. a point (`\\.*`) and decimals after point (`[0-9]*`).
- Next there is a comma (`,`)
- Group 3: same as group 2.
- Group 4: analog to group 1 we are expecting either a `)` or a `]`.

Here is some random variable cut with quantiles. The function `cut_borders` returns what we are looking for:

```
x <- rnorm(10)

x_groups <- cut(x, quantile(x, 0:4/4), include.lowest= TRUE)

cut_borders(x_groups)
```

Comment: that's nice, but the regex can be massively shortened. We know the cut pattern well. Thus we can for example use `".{1}(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+).{1}"` - no need to look for either [ or (, and the "-" can be made optional with ?. using \\d makes it slightly shorter than [0-9]

Comment: This regex doesn't capture intervals with scientific notation, like `(1.26e+03,1.55e+03]`.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of `tidyr::extract`

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(17)
df <- data.frame(x = cut(300 * runif(100), c(0,25,75,125,175,225,299)))

df %>%
  extract(x, c("start", "end"), "(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)")
#>     start end
#> 1      25  75
#> 2     225 299
#> 3     125 175
#> 4     225 299
#> 5      75 125
#> 6     125 175
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

P.S. Thanks to [user 295691 for the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357000/7941188) and [user machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61757432/7941188) for the first draft of the regex, which is modified here. Both +1 :)