# Is there a tidyr::extract equivalent for character vectors?

Tags: r

I was pondering on this after having come across [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356108/output-a-numeric-value-from-cut-in-r/67481469#67481469).

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(x = cut(runif(100), c(0,25,75,125,175,225,299)))
```

`tidyr::extract` does a nice job splitting into groups defined by the regex:

```
df %>%
  extract(x, c("start", "end"), "(\\d+),(\\d+)") %>% head
#>   start end
#> 1     0  25
#> 2     0  25
#> 3     0  25
#> 4     0  25
#> 5     0  25
#> 6     0  25
```

Desired output on a character vector. I know you could just create a new function, I wondered if this is already out there.

```
x_chr <- as.character(df$x)
des_res <- str_split(str_extract(x_chr, "(\\d+),(\\d+)"), ",") 

head(des_res)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "0"  "25"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "0"  "25"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "0"  "25"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "0"  "25"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "0"  "25"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "0"  "25"
```

Comment: You could do it by `str_extract_all()`: `str_extract_all(x_chr, "\\d+")`.

Comment: this only works in this example - I'd like a way to actually split into defined groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strcapture` in base R :

```
strcapture("(\\d+),(\\d+)", x_chr, 
           proto = list(start = numeric(), end = numeric()))

#    start end
#1       0  25
#2       0  25
#3       0  25
#4       0  25
#5       0  25
#6       0  25
#...
#...
```

You can also use `stringr::str_match` :

```
stringr::str_match(x_chr, "(\\d+),(\\d+)")[, -1]
```

In `str_match`, 1st column returns the complete pattern whereas all the subsequent columns are the capture groups.

Comment: nice, I definitely didn’t know that:) do you know of a stringi or stringr equivalent? don’t worry if not

Comment: Yes, you can use `str_match`/`stri_match`. Updated the answer.