# findInterval() when x is on upper interval border value

Tags: r, data-binding, intervals

I need to get the interval boders from `cut()` output. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356108/output-a-numeric-value-from-cut-in-r) question that suggests to use `findInterval()` but it does not work as expected if value of `x` is same as the upper border of `cut(x)`. See here:

```
x <- 1:3
breaks <- c(min(x), 2, max(x))
interval <- findInterval(x, breaks)

data.frame(x,
           groups= cut(x, breaks, include.lowest= TRUE),
           x_lower= breaks[interval],
           x_upper= breaks[interval + 1],
           interval)

  x groups x_lower x_upper interval
1 1  [1,2]       1       2        1
2 2  [1,2]       2       3        2
3 3  [2,3]       3       NA       3
```

I am happy how `cut()` makes `groups` from `x` but `x_lower` and `x_upper` in row 2 and 3 are not as expected. In row two `x` is 2, `groups` is `[1,2]`, so I expect `x_lower` to be `1` and `x_upper` to be `2`. And in row 3 `x` is 3, `groups` is `[2,3]`, so I expect `x_lower` to be `2` and `x_upper` to be `3`. If you play around with data you will see that `findinterval()` returns lower and upper values of `groups` if the `x` value is same as the upper border value in `groups`. I want to avoid that. How can we achieve this?

**Expected output**

```
structure(list(x = 1:3, groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c([1,2]", "(2,3]"), class = "factor"), x_lower = c(1, 1, 2), x_upper = c(2, 2, 3), interval = c(1, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**Remark**
I do want to use `findInterval()` and I can not use `labels[as.numeric(groups)]` as suggested in another post of the [question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356108/output-a-numeric-value-from-cut-in-r). This is because in my situation `x` is sometime a numeric, sometime a Date/ POSIXct/ts/... vector, thus, using `as.numeric()` is not save for me.

Comment: `findInterval(x, breaks, rightmost.closed = TRUE, left.open = TRUE)`?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Hallelujah! I tried different argument values but obviously not the combination of both being `TRUE`. THAT IS GREAT!