# Assign value to specific range

Tags: r, data.table

I have an easy question to figure out:

```
value
1000
2500
5080
10009
```

I want to specify `value` to an interval:

```
value    Range
1000     0-1000
2500     1001-5000
5080     5001-10000
10009    10001-20000
```

I try this:

```
dt[, Range := ifelse(value < 1001, "0-1000", ifelse(1000 < value < 5001, "1001-5000", ifelse(5000 < value < 10001, "5001-10000", "10001-20000")))
```

However, I got `Error: unexpected '<' in "dt[, Range := ifelse(value < 1001, "0-1000", ifelse(1000 < value <"`

Any help?

EDIT:

This question is not asking for the best way to convert a continuous variable to a factor. It is asking for debugging help with the reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(value = c(1000, 2500, 5080, 10009))
dt[, Range := ifelse(value < 1001, "0-1000", ifelse(1000 < value < 5001, "1001-5000", ifelse(5000 < value < 10001, "5001-10000", "10001-20000")))
# produces the error above
```

Comment: See `help("cut")` for a better solution than nested `ifelse`.

Comment: And because you are using data.table: `ifelse` is slow.

Comment: Possible use of `cut` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559076/convert-continuous-numeric-values-to-discrete-categories-defined-by-intervals

Comment: Isn't your problem the line `ifelse(1000 < value < 5001,....` as noted in the answer below? R does not take two-way inequalities. You need to break it down

Comment: To those voting to close due to a typo. It's not a typo. It's a non-obvious syntax error that programmers coming from other languages are likely to make. I'd say that makes it a useful question (and answer) for other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like many (some) errors, it means what it says. Unlike python, R can't interpret `1000 < value < 5001`.  Instead you need to use `1000 < value & value < 5001`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(value = c(1000, 2500, 5080, 10009))
dt[, Range := ifelse(value < 1001, "0-1000", ifelse(1000 < value & value < 5001, "1001-5000", ifelse(5000 < value & value < 10001, "5001-10000", "10001-20000")))]
dt
   value       Range
1:  1000      0-1000
2:  2500   1001-5000
3:  5080  5001-10000
4: 10009 10001-20000
```

As @akrun mentioned, you may be better off with a factor. Here's an example:

```
dt[, Range := cut(value, breaks = c(0, 1001, 5001, 10001, 20001), labels = c("0-1000", "1001-5000", "5001-10000", "10001-20000"))]
```

This produces a data.table that displays the same way, but extracting the `Range` column will give you a factor corresponding to the ranges.

Comment: thanks. your right. I am learning Python recently and I confused with R that I already know. Apprecate again.

Comment: Instead of multiple `ifelse`, you can use `cut` or `findInterval`

Comment: `cut` is great! maybe you can add a Python way to do this. I think some programmers may meet this kind of issue when they use different languages.