# R data.table - complex filter with inequalities

Tags: r, data.table

This should be simple to solve but I just got stuck.

I have a `data.table` which I need to create complex filtering on as shown in the picture. Essentially, it's akin to indexing function in excel, but I need to do this with the lowest memory footprint possible.

I am building a two-dimensional lookup function. Think of v1 as a category - it can only be "one" "two" or "three". Think of v2 as a range of numeric values. I first specify v1. This will always be "==" exactly equal. Then I want to allocate `6`, the value I feed `exampledt[v1=="one" & v2 >= 6, v3 ]` to pick up the corresponding v3 value. The catch is that `6` matches at least two rows. This is the problem here, I want to exploit the table index to avoid having to create all `if(v2[i]>=` permutations. I need to allocate `6` to a vector of ranges that goes from `(inf-16], (16-6],(6,-inf)`

If I feed "one" and 6, I want to be given the value of  i=1,j=2.

If I feed "one" and 5, I want to be given the value of  i=1,j=3.

If I feed "two" and 17, I want to be given the value of i=2,j=2.

I would prefer to avoid the `5.999` hack and it needs to work for the boundary cases as well. How would I go about using the inequalities? Could I maybe exploit the data.table indexing?

[image]

```
  exampledt <- setDT(data.frame(

     c("one" , "one", "one",
       "two" , "two","two",
       "three" , "three", "three" ),

     (c(16,6, 5.9999 ,
        NA,6, 5.9999 ,
        NA,22,21.9999)
     )
     ,letters[1:9]
     ))
  colnames(exampledt)<-c("v1","v2","v3")

  #I tried this but the edge cases need additional logic which I need to avoid
  exampledt[v1=="one" & v2 >= 6, v3 ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output? If the values change, a function would be useful

Comment: @akrun If I feed "one" and 6, I want to be given the value of i=1,j=2.

If I feed "one" and 5, I want to be given the value of i=1,j=3.
If I feed "two" and 17, I want to be given the value of i=2,j=2.

Comment: If you use `f1 <- function(dt, val1, val2) dt[v1 == val1 & v2 >= val2]` and then apply that function, would that solve `f1(exampledt, "one", 6)`

Comment: added v3 for expected output. @akrun Agreed - It would but then I would get all values for which v2 >= val2. Whereas I need the v3 which matches the image I linked. The inequalities and the edge cases are the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me from the image

Comment: If you run the code, you will get two v3 letters - "a" and "b". The desired output is "a".

Comment: what's the question? sorry, I don't get the logic. It seems like random indexes. What if you feed the values "four" and 152; or the values "whatever" 7?

Comment: I am building a two-dimensional lookup function. Think of v1 as a category - it can only be "one" "two" or "three". Think of v2 as a range of numeric values. I first specify v1. This will always be "==" exactly equal. Then I want to allocate 6, the value I feed `exampledt[v1=="one" & v2 >= 6, v3 ]` to pick up the corresponding v3 value.

Comment: Added more detail on main body

Comment: It's the same problem as this q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624656/assign-value-to-specific-range