# How do we use global variable in r inside a quotation

Tags: r, loops, global-variables

I wrote all these myself (please look at the codes below ###) but I think there must be some way to do this inside a loop. How do I edit the code to write a loop something like:

```
i=10

for (i in 10 to 80){

    j=i+5

    age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=i &        
               age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<j] <- "Between i and j-1"

    i=j
 }
```

I don't know how to use `i/j` inside a quotation mark.

#

```
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event] <- "Above 85"    
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<5]<-"Below 5"     
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=5 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<10]<-"Between 5 to 9"     
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=10 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<15]<- "Between 10 to 14"    
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=15 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<20]<- "Between 15 to 19"    
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=20 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<25]<- "Between 20 to 24"    
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=25 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<30]<- "Between 25 to 29"    
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=30 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<35]<- "Between 30 to 34"    
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=35 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<40]<- "Between 35 to 39"    
  age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=40 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<45]<-"Between 40 to 44"      
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=45 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<50]<- "Between 45 to 49"    
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=50 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<55]<-"Between 50 to 54"
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=55 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<60]<- "Between 55 to 59"
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=60 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<65]<- "Between 60 to 64"
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=65 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<70]<- "Between 65 to 69"
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=70 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<75]<- "Between 70 to 74"
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=75 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<80]<- "Between 75 to 79"
age_only$agecat[age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event>=80 & age_only$CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event<85]<- "Between 80 to 84"`
```

Comment: I _think_ you should have a look at `?cut` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559076/convert-continuous-numeric-values-to-discrete-categories-defined-by-intervals

Comment: *"I don't know how to use i/j inside a quotation mark"* Are you after `sprintf("Between %i and %i", i, j - 1)`?

Comment: While i'd advise not to go down the loop route, you can create a string by pasteing the parts together: `paste("Between", i, "and", j-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cut`:

```
age_only <- within(age_only, {
    agecat = cut(CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event, breaks = c(seq(0, 85, 5), 120))

   levels(agecat) <- sub("(\\(|\\[)(\\d*), ?(\\d*)(\\]|\\))", "Between \\2 and \\3",levels(agecat)) 
})
```

`within` lets me modify the data frame without having to say `age_only$` many times.  The `sub` command will convert the levels from looking like `(5,10]` to "Between 5 and 10".