# Syntax for ifelse() Function in R Please

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset called `old_images`

One of the columns in this dataset is called `difference`, which can take values between `1` and `1115`.

I also have another column called `Quarter`, which I want to have values of `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4` depending on what Quarter the `difference` value of that row is.

So the rules would be as follows:

If `old_images$difference` is between `1` and `279`, then `old_images$Quarter` = `1`

ELSE

If `old_images$difference` is between `280` and `558`, then `old_images$Quarter` = `2`

ELSE

If `old_images$difference` is between `559` and `837`, then `old_images$Quarter` = `3`

ELSE

If `old_images$difference` is between `838` and `1115`, then `old_images$Quarter` = `4`

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` will be a good option to use in this case.

Comment: @user20650: the question you linked to is not about `ifelse` which OP didn't ask for

Comment: @Tung; agreed, but it provides the same result but in a more efficient way, which seems appropraite

Comment: @EdinPC: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090097/786542) for `case_when` syntax

Comment: @user20650: So it's not a exact duplicate then? `ifelse` is not only used for case like this thus it's good for OP to learn a proper way to use it

Comment: @Tung ; 
I feel it is correct to direct the op to (one of) the preferred ways to do it, 
rather than showing the way not to do it - but perhaps I am wrong.
Others who disagree can vote to reopen -
  the beauty of community moderation.
(There will be exact duplicates floating about where the same question was asked 
and likely advised to use `cut` etc. 
If you can find one I'll add it to the list of 
duplicate answers.

Comment: @Tung, thank you very much for the link. Ended up clicking on your link, which led to another link, then another, then another - ended up with about 20 tabs open haha. Tried a few of the methods, but no joy. However, MKR has provided a solution below that works perfectly. Thank-you for your help though! Very much appreciated. Have a good evening.

Comment: @user20650: can you add this link to the list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement
EdinPC: you're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `between` and `case_when` from `dplyr` package as:

```
 library(dplyr)

  old_images <- old_images %>% mutate(Quarter  = case_when(
  between(difference, 1, 279) ~ 1,
  between(difference, 280, 558) ~ 2,
  between(difference, 559, 837) ~ 3,
  between(difference, 838, 115) ~ 4,
  TRUE                          ~ 4
                        ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MKR, this worked perfectly!