# Convert integer vector to most proximate bins

Tags: r

Apologies if this is an obvious one.

I have a numeric vector

```
nv <- round(rnorm(100, 100, 10), 0)
```

And then I have a separate set of bins

```
bins <- seq(90, 110, 5)
```

I want to recode the nv vector into the most proximate bin value (in the real data, the bins are not so neatly organized.)

Thanks

Comment: "in the real data, the bins are not so neatly organized" - Are the bins evenly spaced (constant width) or not?

Comment: Google "R histogram unequal bins". There are many solutions... I suspect that their approach can be applied to this situation. I know that in Matlab the function `histc` will do exactly what you want; if you can find the R equivalent you're home and dry.

Comment: It looks that either `findInterval` or `cut` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13482987/1967396) will get you very close to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floris was exactly right with their suggestion of `histc` --the `pracma` library has a seemingly identical function.